# Any experience using scala with CUBA platform ? What is required?

Tags: scala, web-services, cuba-platform

I have recently found out about web RAD tools. Of those CUBA platform and wavemaker seem the most interesting to me. I have noticed that CUBA platform offers an scala plugin but is not even mentioned in the developer's manual.
Has anyone used this for some project? Does it offer any benefit?

Answer (score 0):

i used a lot wavemakeronline cause i been using before they change to angular 
and using scala not sure in wavemaker ..just i can use java services so maybe there can be used